# NestedTable in SYS schema Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, types, oracle11g

```
 desc sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
 sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000)
```

I found DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COL1 for table of varchar2.I was searching on the SYS schema if there is defined type for table of numbers?. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Only reason for using the types in SYS schema is to avoid creating new types in the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dbms_sql` package has a number of [predefined collection types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i1027634), including `VARCHAR2_TABLE` and `NUMBER_TABLE`.  I'm not sure whether you are exclusively looking for SQL collection types or whether these PL/SQL collection types are sufficient.

Comment: desc DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2_TABLE
ERROR:                                      
------------------------------------------- 
ERROR: object VARCHAR2_TABLE does not exist

Comment: I checked the dbms_sql and it look like the number table and varchar table doesn't exist.

Comment: @user1118468 - Are you implying that you are only looking for SQL collection types?  As I said, these are PL/SQL collections, not SQL collections.  They're in the `DBMS_SQL` package owned by `SYS`.  You can't `desc` them this way though you can use them in your own PL/SQL.

Comment: I was looking to use these types in PL/SQL procedure as input parameters.

Comment: @user1118468 - Then you just need PL/SQL collections.  The `dbms_sql` package has those types (and a number of others).  You can't `desc` PL/SQL types the same way that you do SQL types, though.

Comment: What is the basic difference between SQL & PL/SQL collection types?. Which one should we use in procedure and/or in SQL statement?.

Comment: @user1118468 - SQL data types exist in the schema.  PL/SQL data types exist in PL/SQL objects (packages, procedures, functions, etc.)  Certain types of collections can only be defined in PL/SQL (associative arrays, for example).  SQL collections can be used in SQL statements that are outside of PL/SQL blocks, PL/SQL collections cannot (I think there are some 12c changes here but I'd have to double-check that).  Generally, I'd use PL/SQL types unless there was some reason that you need a SQL collection type.

Answer (score 1):

There is a predefined table of number type: sys.odciNumberList that you can use when dealing with collections of numbers.